# Does Google store and use data used for googleVis visualisations?

Tags: r, google-api, google-visualization, privacy, googlevis

I'd like to create some interactive charts using googleVis package in R but I am a bit hesitant as I am not sure if Google will store the data I want to visualize. I have read their terms and conditions [https://developers.google.com/terms/ ] (particularly the 'Content' section) and it seems to suggest that they can but I was never any good at legal jargon.

Does visualizing my data through the API mean I submitted 'content' to Google and they can subsequently store and use it?

If so, are there any alternatives i.e. r packages that can create interactive dashboards and motion charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Bottom of the page ->

Data policy

All code and data are processed and rendered in the browser. No data is sent to any server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about googles policy on data, but here are some alternatives:

- [rCharts](http://rcharts.io/)
- [Shiny](http://rcharts.io/)
- [htmlwidgets](http://rcharts.io/)

Comment: I'll check them out. Thanks a lot for your help.